# Bounding reachability of damped harmonic oscillator using barrier certificates

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, control-theory, linear-control

I'm trying to prove that, under certain conditions, a damped harmonic oscillator that starts on one side of the equilibrium remains on that side of the equilibrium. More precisely, consider the following system

$$x(t)' = v(t)$$
$$v(t)' = -kx(t)-cv(t)$$

for constants $k$ and $c$ such that $c^2 - 4k \geq 0$ (the system is critically or overdamped). Assume that the initial position $x_0$ and initial velocity $v_0$ satisfy $x_0 \geq 0$ and $-v_0 \leq x_0\frac{c}{2\sqrt{k}}$. Now prove that for all time, $x \geq 0$.

I believe that this can be done by examining the solution to this system. However, I'm trying to prove this property using barrier certificates, a concept similar to Lyapunov functions. In particular, I'm looking for a function $B(x,v)$ such that

1. $B(x,v) > 0$ for all $x < 0$
2. $\frac{dB(x,v)}{dt} \leq 0$

The existence of such a function guarantees that if the system starts in a state where $B(x,v)$ is non-positive, then $x$ will never be less than 0. This function is called a barrier certificate.

Comment: I think it will be easier to look at the constants, as a function of the initial conditions, by which the combination of the general solutions are multiplied. Since if they are both positive, then solution can't become negative.

Comment: @fibonatic My goal is to prove the bounds with a barrier certificate, even if it's not the best way to solve this problem. I'm really just trying to learn how barrier certificates work through a hopefully simple example. The main advantage that barrier certificates offer is that they work for non-linear systems as well in which it's harder to come up with a closed-form solution.

Comment: Could you clarify the definition of barrier certificate? Because I am just not convinced why this thing works exactly. Also you can use the fact that you know straight line solutions for this system and can choose function $B(x, v)$ to have straight line level sets parallel to one of these straight lines.

Comment: @Evgeny A barrier certificate $B(x,v)$ is a function which is positive in the unsafe region (in my example, $B(x,v) > 0$ for $x > 0$) and has non-positive time derivative ($\frac{dB(x,v)}{dt} \leq 0$). The idea is that if the system starts in a state where $B(x,v) \leq 0$, then it will never reach a state where $B(x,v) > 0$.

Comment: @Evgeny Sorry for the potentially stupid question, but what are straight line solutions for the system?

Comment: Since it's a linear system of ODEs its eigenvectors define straight line solutions.

Comment: Sorry, but two parts of barrier certificate definition still don't fit for me. Let me write how I understand it should work. There's a function $B(x, v)$. There's a special region that is defined by inequality $B(x, v) > 0 $. If we know that $\frac{dB(x,v)}{dt} \geqslant 0$ everywhere then it's easy to show that every trajectory that started in $B(x, v) > 0$ can't go out of this domain and enter $B(x, v) \leqslant 0$. But I can't establish correspondence between my understanding and your definition.

Comment: @Evgeny The goal is to find the set of initial states such that if the system starts in these states, it will _not_ enter the unsafe region $x > 0$. In order to do this, you must find a function $B(x,v)$ which is positive in the unsafe region $x > 0$ and does not increase over time, i.e. $\frac{dB(x,v)}{dt} \leq 0$. If we can find such a function, then we know that if the system starts in any state where $B(x,v) \leq 0$ (set of initial states), it will never reach a state where $B(x,v) > 0$ (i.e. the unsafe set $x > 0$).

Comment: Great! We understand it in the same way up to the change of signs :) I think that I could invent a barrier certificate for this problem but the idea behind that is not algorithmic or computational at all -- it just uses the knowledge of equilibrium's eigenspaces.

Comment: @Evgeny Awesome! A general algorithmic approach for finding barrier certificates would be obviously be great, but I'm not sure if one actually exists. Any answer you have would be great. I understand the general concept behind barrier certificates, but I haven't had much luck finding concrete examples of barrier functions online for simple but non-artificial problems. I hope that a barrier certificate for this problem will go a long way towards helping me apply the concept to the problems that interest me.